# Retries from Ingressgateway

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio

Istio has virtual service for pods with istio-proxy side cars but what istio ingress-gateway pod itself , how to enable retries from istio ingressgateway pod.
Use case is that i am seeing 503 error in case of downscaling and want ingressgateway to retry for specific destination

https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Istio mesh represents ingress communication model between external Load Balancer through `istio-ingressgateway` and logical traffic management CRD [*components*](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/), which define a network routes, [Authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication)/[*Authorization*](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization) aspects and service-to-service interactions.

[*Istio Gateway*](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/) as the major contributor with an edge `istio-ingressgateway` service describes essential information about ports and protocols for *HTTP/HTTS/TCP* connections that are entering the service mesh and a way how to manage the further routing scenarios, therefore `istio-ingressgateway` does not decide itself about network traffic workflow and target application endpoints.

[*Retries*](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#retries) concept in Istio is actually enclosed in routing rules and composed within [VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/) resource, showing us the main principle of network request re-attempts and their timeouts in case of initial call's failure.

When Istio `istio-ingressgateway` Pod starts it retrieves the discovery data about Envoy [sidecars](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/) from [*Pilot*](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#pilot), approaching the desired state through `pilot-agent` specific [flags](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/pilot-agent/#pilot-agent-proxy).

However, I couldn't determine the reported 503 error, during down-scaling `istio-ingressgateway` replicas in [Istio 1.3](https://istio.io/news/2019/announcing-1.3/).